# Collision not detecting while animating object

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am trying to animate the cylindrical rod on the towel from down to up animation and during that animation the collision is not detectable in my towel and rod.

Towel is going down, Rod is going up

Cloth simulation has been applied over plane and collision is applied on cylinder, self-collision is also selected over cloth , still nothing happened. Tried many ways, but nothing help, can you help me. thanks

[Blend File Download](https://easyupload.io/f3oxns)

Comment: Your Blend file link is not working

Comment: its available..